# Why are my labels not aligned with my lines?

Tags: pine-script

I've got a sample bit of code here, pulled from a larger script, however for weekly and monthly attempts to draw these labels, the labels end up completely below the lines that are drawn, and I can't figure out why.

Unrelated: I know this can be cleaned up with arrays, this is still just a rough code out I'm trying to get working first.

[image]

```
//@version=4
study("Test Weekly Script", overlay = true)

//colors
var color gray = #D1D4DC

//Fetched Values - Weekly
wClose = security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, resolution = "W", expression = close[1], lookahead=true)
wHigh = security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, resolution = "W", expression = high[1], lookahead=true)
wLow = security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, resolution = "W", expression = low[1], lookahead=true)

//Calculate Weekly Pivots
wPivot = (wHigh + wLow + wClose)/3
wR1 = (wPivot * 2) - wLow
wR2 = wPivot + (wHigh - wLow)
wR3 = wR1 + (wHigh - wLow)
wS1 = (wPivot * 2) - wHigh
wS2 = wPivot - (wHigh - wLow)
wS3 = wS1 - (wHigh - wLow)

//Weekly Lines
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wPivot, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wPivot, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wR1, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wR1, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wR2, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wR2, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wR3, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wR3, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wS1, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wS1, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wS2, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wS2, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = wS3, x2 = bar_index, y2 = wS3, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(gray,25), width = 1)

//Weekly Labels
var label wPivotLabel = label.new(bar_index, wPivot, "Weekly Pivot", style=label.style_none)
var label wR1Label = label.new(bar_index, wR1, "Weekly R1", style=label.style_none)
var label wR2Label = label.new(bar_index, wR2, "Weekly R2", style=label.style_none)
var label wR3Label = label.new(bar_index, wR3, "Weekly R3", style=label.style_none)
var label wS1Label = label.new(bar_index, wS1, "Weekly S1", style=label.style_none)
var label wS2Label = label.new(bar_index, wS2, "Weekly S2", style=label.style_none)
var label wS3Label = label.new(bar_index, wS3, "Weekly S3", style=label.style_none)

//Print label once
label.set_x(wPivotLabel, bar_index)
label.set_x(wR1Label, bar_index)
label.set_x(wR2Label, bar_index)
label.set_x(wR3Label, bar_index)
label.set_x(wS1Label, bar_index)
label.set_x(wS2Label, bar_index)
label.set_x(wS3Label, bar_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also update the y coordinates, because they're var labels, it's only being set once on initialization. For example replace existing label.set lines :
`label.set_xy(wPivotLabel, bar_index, wPivot)` etc

Comment: Thank you!  That'll do it!